# C++ what is the purpose of putting an operator at the end of a class?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

Let's say I have a simple c++ component called Component like this :

```
class Component {
 public:
  explicit Component(int i)
  : _integer(i) {
  }

  ~Component() {
  }

  private:
   int _integer;

  Component(const Component&);
  Component& operator=(const Component&);
};
```

I usually found in the code I read the two last instructions but I do not really understand it. Is it mandatory for the correct use of the component ?

Comment: usually it is a C++98/03 trick to disable copy ctor and assignment operator. in C++11 you can use = delete instead (also in public section)

Comment: There is no such thing as the end of the class. What matters is the access specifier in which the members are declared.

Answer (score 11):

This declares an overload for `operator=`. Overloading the operator would normally allow you to control how assignment expressions (`a = b`) are carried out.

In this case however, what's of interest is not the fact the operator is last, but that it's under the private access specifier. This means that outside code may not preform assignment (or copy construction for that matter, since the copy c'tor is there as well) of `Component` objects.

Code inside the class (in member functions) may assign and copy construct. But I would say that it's unlikely that it does. Marking those two special member functions private, and not defining them was the C++03 way of disabling copying for the class. One had to declare them to prevent the compiler from synthesizing the default copy constructor and assignment operator.

In modern C++, one may turn the "undefined symbol" error into a compile time error, by explicitly deleting those functions:

```
Component(const Component&) = delete;
Component& operator=(const Component&) = delete;
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you recommend to always disable copying for a class ?

Comment: @klaus - This highly depends on the class. So I can't give absolute advice here. I would say however, that if you write a class that is heavy in logic, it may be a good idea to disable copying by default. You can always add it later if you need it.

Comment: It's usually good to prevent copying (and, implicitly, moving) of polymorphic base classes, as such objects often have identity (can't just change the address), and/or [slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) is harmful for them. If your base class has at least one pure virtual (i.e. `virtual ... = 0;`) method, declaring the copy assignment operator as deleted is sufficient: `T &operator =(const T&) = delete;`. Otherwise, also declare the copy constructor as deleted. If you just want to prevent slicing, you can instead declare them as protected and define them as `= default`.

Answer (score 0):

Placing declarations of the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator in the private section of the class makes objects of the class non-copyable.